# Terminology: Intersection of a Spherical Zone and Lune

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there a name for the portion of a sphere that is the intersection of a [spherical lune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_lune) and a [spherical zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment) that have the same axis? I.e., the region of a sphere bound by min and max latitudes and longitudes?

[image: lat/lon bounding box]

*(image borrowed from [Area of a spherical rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613456/area-of-a-spherical-rectangle))*

I'm tempted to use the phrase "spherical rectangle," but that [appears to mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle#Other_rectangles) the portion of a sphere bound by four "great circle arcs which meet at equal angles greater than 90°."

[image: spherical rectangle]

*(image borrowed from [How to calculate the area covered by any spherical rectangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205927/how-to-calculate-the-area-covered-by-any-spherical-rectangle))*

Comment: Just found another question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457023/whats-the-name-of-each-pseudo-rectangle-in-a-spherical-surface) that is the same as mine. Self-flagged. :D